# Biblatex, basic usage, references not working

Tags: biblatex, compiling, biber, mactex

I'm using BibLaTex for the first time and I have followed some Web tutorials to use it, but I cannot get it working properly. First, I had a problem when changing the reference style from alphanumeric to numeric, BibLaTex would not render the Bibliography page, but when I've tried to create a self-contained example today, I can't get the bibliography page rendered even if setting the style to alphanumeric.
These are my files:

main.tex

```
% !TeX encoding = ISO-8859-1

\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}

\newcommand{\authorname}{V{\'i}ctor Caballero}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=numeric 
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Abstract}
\parencite{hewitt1973universal}


\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

references.bib

```
@inproceedings{hewitt1973universal,
    title={A universal modular actor formalism for artificial intelligence},
    author={Hewitt, Carl and Bishop, Peter and Steiger, Richard},
    booktitle={Proceedings of the 3rd international joint conference on Artificial intelligence},
    pages={235--245},
    year={1973},
    organization={Morgan Kaufmann Publishers Inc.}
}

@techreport{agha1985actors,
    title={Actors: A model of concurrent computation in distributed systems.},
    author={Agha, Gul A},
    year={1985},
    institution={DTIC Document}
}
```

No errors are shown when compiling the main.tex file.

I'm using the MacTex distribution with TexStudio,
Biber is configured for the build as shown in the figure below:
[image]

main.log
See full main.log [here](https://gist.github.com/vicaba/77212bf2de5d8b48c815)

... After some content ...

```
Now handling font encoding OT1 ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OT1

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu
File: ot1enc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A1 (decimal 161)
   defining Unicode char U+00A3 (decimal 163)
   defining Unicode char U+00B8 (decimal 184)
   defining Unicode char U+00BF (decimal 191)
   defining Unicode char U+00C5 (decimal 197)
   defining Unicode char U+00C6 (decimal 198)
   defining Unicode char U+00D8 (decimal 216)
   defining Unicode char U+00DF (decimal 223)
   defining Unicode char U+00E6 (decimal 230)
   defining Unicode char U+00EC (decimal 236)
   defining Unicode char U+00ED (decimal 237)
   defining Unicode char U+00EE (decimal 238)
   defining Unicode char U+00EF (decimal 239)
   defining Unicode char U+00F8 (decimal 248)
   defining Unicode char U+0131 (decimal 305)
   defining Unicode char U+0141 (decimal 321)
   defining Unicode char U+0142 (decimal 322)
   defining Unicode char U+0152 (decimal 338)
   defining Unicode char U+0153 (decimal 339)
   defining Unicode char U+2013 (decimal 8211)
   defining Unicode char U+2014 (decimal 8212)
   defining Unicode char U+2018 (decimal 8216)
   defining Unicode char U+2019 (decimal 8217)
   defining Unicode char U+201C (decimal 8220)
   defining Unicode char U+201D (decimal 8221)
)
Now handling font encoding OMS ...
... processing UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMS

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu
File: omsenc.dfu 2015/06/27 v1.1n UTF-8 support for inputenc
   defining Unicode char U+00A7 (decimal 167)
   defining Unicode char U+00B6 (decimal 182)
   defining Unicode char U+00B7 (decimal 183)
   defining Unicode char U+2020 (decimal 8224)
   defining Unicode char U+2021 (decimal 8225)
   defining Unicode char U+2022 (decimal 8226)
)
Now handling font encoding OMX ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding OMX
Now handling font encoding U ...
... no UTF-8 mapping file for font encoding U
   defining Unicode char U+00A9 (decimal 169)
   defining Unicode char U+00AA (decimal 170)
   defining Unicode char U+00AE (decimal 174)
   defining Unicode char U+00BA (decimal 186)
   defining Unicode char U+02C6 (decimal 710)
   defining Unicode char U+02DC (decimal 732)
   defining Unicode char U+200C (decimal 8204)
   defining Unicode char U+2026 (decimal 8230)
   defining Unicode char U+2122 (decimal 8482)
   defining Unicode char U+2423 (decimal 9251)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
Package: graphicx 2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty
Package: keyval 2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
Package: graphics 2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/graphics.cfg
File: graphics.cfg 2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: pdftex.def on input line 94.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
File: pdftex.def 2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty
Package: infwarerr 2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
\Gread@gobject=\count88
))
\Gin@req@height=\dimen103
\Gin@req@width=\dimen104
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/import/import.sty
Package: import 2009/03/23  v 5.1
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
Package: geometry 2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty
Package: ifpdf 2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
Package ifpdf Info: pdfTeX in PDF mode is detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty
Package: ifvtex 2010/03/01 v1.5 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
Package ifvtex Info: VTeX not detected.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty
Package: ifxetex 2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
)
\Gm@cnth=\count89
\Gm@cntv=\count90
\c@Gm@tempcnt=\count91
\Gm@bindingoffset=\dimen105
\Gm@wd@mp=\dimen106
\Gm@odd@mp=\dimen107
\Gm@even@mp=\dimen108
\Gm@layoutwidth=\dimen109
\Gm@layoutheight=\dimen110
\Gm@layouthoffset=\dimen111
\Gm@layoutvoffset=\dimen112
\Gm@dimlist=\toks17
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
Package: biblatex 2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
Package: biblatex2 2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/A
B)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2015/05/04 v2.2 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count92
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
Package: kvoptions 2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
Package: kvsetkeys 2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
Package: etexcmds 2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty
Package: ifluatex 2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
Package ifluatex Info: LuaTeX not detected.
)
Package etexcmds Info: Could not find \expanded.
(etexcmds)             That can mean that you are not using pdfTeX 1.50 or
(etexcmds)             that some package has redefined \expanded.
(etexcmds)             In the latter case, load this package earlier.
)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
Package: logreq 2010/08/04 v1.0 xml request logger
\lrq@indent=\count93

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def
File: logreq.def 2010/08/04 v1.0 logreq spec v1.0
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
\Urlmuskip=\muskip10
Package: url 2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
)
\c@tabx@nest=\count94
\c@listtotal=\count95
\c@listcount=\count96
\c@liststart=\count97
\c@liststop=\count98
\c@citecount=\count99
\c@citetotal=\count100
\c@multicitecount=\count101
\c@multicitetotal=\count102
\c@instcount=\count103
\c@maxnames=\count104
\c@minnames=\count105
\c@maxitems=\count106
\c@minitems=\count107
\c@citecounter=\count108
\c@savedcitecounter=\count109
\c@uniquelist=\count110
\c@uniquename=\count111
\c@refsection=\count112
\c@refsegment=\count113
\c@maxextratitle=\count114
\c@maxextratitleyear=\count115
\c@maxextrayear=\count116
\c@maxextraalpha=\count117
\c@abbrvpenalty=\count118
\c@highnamepenalty=\count119
\c@lownamepenalty=\count120
\c@maxparens=\count121
\c@parenlevel=\count122
\blx@tempcnta=\count123
\blx@tempcntb=\count124
\blx@tempcntc=\count125
\blx@maxsection=\count126
\blx@maxsegment@0=\count127
\blx@notetype=\count128
\blx@parenlevel@text=\count129
\blx@parenlevel@foot=\count130
\blx@sectionciteorder@0=\count131
\labelnumberwidth=\skip43
\labelalphawidth=\skip44
\biblabelsep=\skip45
\bibitemsep=\skip46
\bibnamesep=\skip47
\bibinitsep=\skip48
\bibparsep=\skip49
\bibhang=\skip50
\blx@bcfin=\read1
\blx@bcfout=\write3
\c@mincomprange=\count132
\c@maxcomprange=\count133
\c@mincompwidth=\count134
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex default data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-dm.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex style data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'alphabetic.dbx' not found.
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load biblatex custom data model...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex-dm.cfg' not found.
\c@afterword=\count135
\c@savedafterword=\count136
\c@annotator=\count137
\c@savedannotator=\count138
\c@author=\count139
\c@savedauthor=\count140
\c@bookauthor=\count141
\c@savedbookauthor=\count142
\c@commentator=\count143
\c@savedcommentator=\count144
\c@editor=\count145
\c@savededitor=\count146
\c@editora=\count147
\c@savededitora=\count148
\c@editorb=\count149
\c@savededitorb=\count150
\c@editorc=\count151
\c@savededitorc=\count152
\c@foreword=\count153
\c@savedforeword=\count154
\c@holder=\count155
\c@savedholder=\count156
\c@introduction=\count157
\c@savedintroduction=\count158
\c@namea=\count159
\c@savednamea=\count160
\c@nameb=\count161
\c@savednameb=\count162
\c@namec=\count163
\c@savednamec=\count164
\c@translator=\count165
\c@savedtranslator=\count166
\c@shortauthor=\count167
\c@savedshortauthor=\count168
\c@shorteditor=\count169
\c@savedshorteditor=\count170
\c@labelname=\count171
\c@savedlabelname=\count172
\c@institution=\count173
\c@savedinstitution=\count174
\c@lista=\count175
\c@savedlista=\count176
\c@listb=\count177
\c@savedlistb=\count178
\c@listc=\count179
\c@savedlistc=\count180
\c@listd=\count181
\c@savedlistd=\count182
\c@liste=\count183
\c@savedliste=\count184
\c@listf=\count185
\c@savedlistf=\count186
\c@location=\count187
\c@savedlocation=\count188
\c@organization=\count189
\c@savedorganization=\count190
\c@origlocation=\count191
\c@savedoriglocation=\count192
\c@origpublisher=\count193
\c@savedorigpublisher=\count194
\c@publisher=\count195
\c@savedpublisher=\count196
\c@language=\count197
\c@savedlanguage=\count198
\c@pageref=\count199
\c@savedpageref=\count200
\shorthandwidth=\skip51
\shortjournalwidth=\skip52
\shortserieswidth=\skip53
\shorttitlewidth=\skip54
\shortauthorwidth=\skip55
\shorteditorwidth=\skip56
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load compatibility code...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'blx-compat.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def
File: blx-compat.def 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex compatibility (PK/JW/AB)
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load generic definitions...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.def' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def
File: biblatex.def 
\c@textcitecount=\count201
\c@textcitetotal=\count202
\c@textcitemaxnames=\count203
\c@biburlnumpenalty=\count204
\c@biburlucpenalty=\count205
\c@biburllcpenalty=\count206
\c@smartand=\count207
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'alphabetic'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'alphabetic.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/alphabetic.bbx
File: alphabetic.bbx 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliography style 'standard'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'standard.bbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx
File: standard.bbx 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex bibliography style (PK/JW/AB)
\c@bbx:relatedcount=\count208
\c@bbx:relatedtotal=\count209
))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load citation style 'numeric'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'numeric.cbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx
File: numeric.cbx 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex citation style (PK/JW/AB)
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\footcitetext'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\supercite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcite'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\textcites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\cites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\parencites'.
Package biblatex Info: Redefining '\smartcites'.
)
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load configuration file...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'biblatex.cfg' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg
File: biblatex.cfg 
)))
Package biblatex Info: Trying to load language 'english'...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'english.lbx' found.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
File: english.lbx 2015/04/19 v3.0 biblatex localization (PK/JW/AB)
)
\@quotelevel=\count210
\@quotereset=\count211

(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 19.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 19.
 (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
\scratchcounter=\count212
\scratchdimen=\dimen113
\scratchbox=\box26
\nofMPsegments=\count213
\nofMParguments=\count214
\everyMPshowfont=\toks18
\MPscratchCnt=\count215
\MPscratchDim=\dimen114
\MPnumerator=\count216
\makeMPintoPDFobject=\count217
\everyMPtoPDFconversion=\toks19
) (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
Package: pdftexcmds 2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO
)
Package pdftexcmds Info: LuaTeX not detected.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@primitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdf@ifprimitive is available.
Package pdftexcmds Info: \pdfdraftmode found.
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/epstopdf-base.sty
Package: epstopdf-base 2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/grfext.sty
Package: grfext 2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty
Package: kvdefinekeys 2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
))
Package grfext Info: Graphics extension search list:
(grfext)             [.png,.pdf,.jpg,.mps,.jpeg,.jbig2,.jb2,.PNG,.PDF,.JPG,.JPE
G,.JBIG2,.JB2,.eps]
(grfext)             \AppendGraphicsExtensions on input line 452.

(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg
File: epstopdf-sys.cfg 2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Liv
e
))
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: pdftex
*geometry* verbose mode - [ preamble ] result:
* driver: pdftex
* paper: a4paper
* layout: <same size as paper>
* layoutoffset:(h,v)=(0.0pt,0.0pt)
* modes: twoside 
* h-part:(L,W,R)=(68.28659pt, 426.79134pt, 102.42995pt)
* v-part:(T,H,B)=(71.13188pt, 702.78308pt, 71.13188pt)
* \paperwidth=597.50787pt
* \paperheight=845.04684pt
* \textwidth=426.79134pt
* \textheight=702.78308pt
* \oddsidemargin=-3.9834pt
* \evensidemargin=30.15996pt
* \topmargin=-38.1381pt
* \headheight=12.0pt
* \headsep=25.0pt
* \topskip=12.0pt
* \footskip=30.0pt
* \marginparwidth=95.0pt
* \marginparsep=10.0pt
* \columnsep=10.0pt
* \skip\footins=10.8pt plus 4.0pt minus 2.0pt
* \hoffset=0.0pt
* \voffset=0.0pt
* \mag=1000
* \@twocolumnfalse
* \@twosidetrue
* \@mparswitchtrue
* \@reversemarginfalse
* (1in=72.27pt=25.4mm, 1cm=28.453pt)

Package biblatex Info: Input encoding 'utf8' detected.
Package biblatex Info: Automatic encoding selection.
(biblatex)             Assuming data encoding 'utf8'.
\openout3 = `main.bcf'.

Package biblatex Info: Trying to load bibliographic data...
Package biblatex Info: ... file 'main.bbl' not found.
No file main.bbl.
Package biblatex Info: Reference section=0 on input line 19.
Package biblatex Info: Reference segment=0 on input line 19.
Chapter 1.

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'hewitt1973universal' on page 1 undefined on input line
 22.


LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 25.

[1


{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

Package logreq Info: Writing requests to 'main.run.xml'.
\openout1 = `main.run.xml'.

 ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 7541 strings out of 493093
 126331 string characters out of 6134989
 545744 words of memory out of 5000000
 10957 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4851 words of font info for 18 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 44i,4n,35p,794b,729s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb
></usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr12.pfb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 19275 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 16 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 10 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Comment: The example is ok. What is the content of the blg-file?

Comment: Can you show us the log file? You are loading option utf8 for `inputenc`, but your documents introducs itself as latin1. Is that on purpose?

Comment: you have to run pdflatex - biber - pdflatex

Comment: @UlrikeFischer did you mean the log file? I've added its content in the question. I see some errors at the end but I don't know what to do to solve them.

Comment: @Johannes_B Yeah, it's not on purpose but since it is a comment I don't think that it is the problem. Can a comment be a problem in latex?

Comment: @musicman sry, I'm new to LaTeX, can I run this commands via TexStudio? How?

Comment: This comment is processed by your editor.It is quite likely that the editor is saving your files as latin1, which will clash with option `utf8` for inputenc.

Comment: @Johannes_B removing the comment did not work, I'm trying to configure TexStudio to run the commands musicman says, but for some strange reason, after changing the preferences, TexStudio reverts preferences back to default.

Comment: That encoding issue is unrelated to the bibliography issue (at least i guess without the blg). Have you pressed `F11`-button in between your latex runs?

Comment: @musicman solution worked, btw, what does "blg" mean?

Comment: blg=biblatex logfile

Comment: @musicman can you post your solution as an answer so I can check it as the correct answer?